# extend a jQuery Object to my own Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

My problem is the following code!
I want extend a jQuery Object to my XjQuery object and i seems to be work.
but in the each function where i will find the object the function myfunc is not declared
whats wrong here?

cheers and

sorry for my poor english

```
    XjQuery = function()
    {           
        var jq = $("<div id=xjq>hallo</div>");
        $.extend(this, jq);
    }
    XjQuery.prototype.myfunc = function() {
        this.append("<p>myfunc called</p>");
    }
    xjq = new XjQuery();

    xjq.myfunc(); // this works
    $("#maindiv").append(xjq); // works also 
    $("#maindiv").find("#xjq").each(function() {
        $(this).myfunc(); // doesn't work
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `each`, `this` is a native DOM element, and `$(this)` is a jQuery object.  You need to "convert" the jQuery object into your `xjQuery` object.

Why are you making an `xJquery` object in the first place?  Why not make a [jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)?

```
jQuery.fn.myfunc = function() {
    this.append("<p>myfunc called</p>");
};
```

Then you can do `$("#maindiv").myfunc()`.

EDIT: To "cast" a jQuery object as a `xjQuery` object, you can modify the constructor like this:

```
XjQuery = function(jq)
{           
    jq = typeof jq === 'undefined' ? $("<div id=xjq>hallo</div>") : $(jq);
    $.extend(this, jq);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$("#maindiv").find("#xjq").each(function() {
    new XjQuery(this).myfunc();
});
```

Comment: Rocket is correct, the right way to add extensions to jQuery is via plugins.  These extensions will show up as normal methods on the `$` object.  For example `$('#a-div-id').myPluginMethod(anArgument, anotherArgument)`

Comment: I forgot to mention, [jQuery documentation for plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: My extension its just an example i have more different objects that will be extended from jQuery and each object have different member functions

Comment: @helmi: The problem is still that you need to convert from jQuery to your "extended" objects.  You can make a function to do that I guess, using `$.extend`.

Comment: is there a posibility to cast the native object to my extended object

Comment: @helmi: You can edit your constructor to take a parameter, then use that.

Comment: mhh have you a small sample or can you explain
a i see you put the sample to the answer